# All the info of Google "My Maps" in offline mode

Tags: google-maps, offline, maps

Using Android 5.1, I would like to use all the information of "My Maps" in offline mode, but I do not find the way to do it.

I mean, I've downloaded the map of a city to be used offline and it works ok. If I am online, I can insert one of "My Maps" and browse over that map the points I inserted (click over them and see the associated information). However, if I am offline, I can not see that information. Does anybody know how to store it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply put, you can't do pretty much anything other than viewing the map. Check out the [support page](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273567?hl=en) of the Google maps.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and came across this: http://travelingchic.com/how-to-create-a-custom-google-maps-itinerary-use-it-offline/